# Why does my app works on my computer but not on others

Tags: c#, dll, windows-forms-designer, biometrics, zkteco

im doing an app in c# windowns form that register the entries of the employees with a biometric device. I did a setup and send to my other computer to test if it would work on another device. Everything works fine except the functionalities that work directly with the biometric device(**remembering that works perfectly fine on my computer**).
I already checked one by one every dll, and didnt noticed nothing missing.

The error is the following :

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00853A19-BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61F} failed due to the following error:
80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).**

Print of the error :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5vk2.png

Comment: Suggestion: Take your CLSID and search Regedit on your dev machine. The CLSID will lead you to the entry point, this will be the dll that needs installing on other machines, either with a setup installer or via command line registration.

Comment: Maybe ? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663994/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x80040154

Comment: I googled for the CLSID and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53281508/zkemkeeper-dll-not-working-after-deploying-class-not-registered) SO post. They have the same problem, same tech etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks, you have the COM DLLs registered in your computer but not on the other computer. So naturally it would fail without making any change in the actual software you developed. SDK package usually has register.bat or something similar to that. Find it and run the batch file, then your software would work.

Comment: I already solved the problem and it was exactly what you said, i tranfered the sdk package to the other computer and runned the register.bat and after that it worked fine. I didnt close the question because i dont know how xD im new here. But thanks anyway