# CZKEM does not contain definition (zkemkeeper-related)

Tags: visual-studio, interop, zkteco, zkemkeeper

I am using the Standalone SDK from ZKTEco for a fingerprint scanner. I need to add some custom functionality.

I've downloaded the SDK along with the Demo project. Now when I try to build the Demo project, I get the following error

```
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'CZKEM' does not contain a definition for 'SetUserValidDate' 
and no accessible extension method 'SetUserValidDate' accepting a first 
argument of type 'CZKEM' could be found (are you missing a using directive 
or an assembly reference?)"
```

I have referenced the `zkemkeeper.dll` file in my project. I'm using VB 2017 on Windows 10. I've tried to look for `Embed Interop Types` property but I cannot find it in the properties of`zkemkeeper`

How can I solve this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I order to make any project referencing the zkemkeeper compile, you need to register it in the windows system.

You should have received a bat file among the dll files called "Register_SDK" as shown in [image: this picture]. This is used to register the zkemkeeper in windows. If not, then you must register it manually.

Please, read these posts:

[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923806/error-when-inserting-finger-print-data-into-database-table/52925455#52925455)

[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53281508/zkemkeeper-dll-not-working-after-deploying-class-not-registered/53300995#53300995)

There is also a [starting guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/%2FArticles%2F1104538%2FCsharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started) for newbies already written by another member of this community, it´s written in c#.

Best regards.