# How to resolve COMException 0x80040154 in x64 Windows Forms program while using zkemkeeper?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, .net-4.8, zkemkeeper

I want to get 64-bit output from my program, but it gives an error when running.

```
 zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass cZKEMClass = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();
```

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException HResult=0x80040154 Message=Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00853A19-BD51-419B-9269-2DABE57EB61F} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`

I copied and registered zkemkeeper.dll in syswow64 and system 32, but the problem is still not solved.

Comment: How did you register it? Clearly, Windows does not think that it is registered.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923806/error-when-inserting-finger-print-data-into-database-table/52925455#52925455

Comment: You will first have to obtain the 64-bit version of zkemkeeper.  Tough shopping, I see no evidence that the product owner has made it available.